# Publishing Queue stuck in "Ready for Transport" status in SDL 9

Tags: sdl-tridion, publishingfailed, transport

Publishing was working for me earlier, now the items are getting stuck in "Ready for Transport" status. I've checked the log for deployer and transport but dont see any specific error. I tried restarting the publisher and transport service as well, but no luck. Please suggest.

Comment: There has to be something in the logs. Sometimes i've seen timeout issues only appear after an hour or so. I've seen the cause to be disk space quote running out on the incoming folder on CD and within temp folders where the zip gets unpacked. So keep checking the logs.  Also I've seen setups where logs get redirected to other scopes (e.g. different partitions or app server cluster), so do make sure you're looking at the right logs.

Comment: publishing of an item failed, and seeing this error in transaction details: "Transport service failed to transport. <Summary stare="Failed" referenceId="tcm:0-xxx-xxxxx"><Error>Unexpected error occurred. Retry limit exceeded.</Error><Processing><Context topic="Content Delivery"><IsRollbackOnFailure /></Context></Processing><Target /></Summary> @NickoliRoussakov

Comment: What’s your timeout and retry set to? Are there any other impacts on network traffic etc. Check your sql logs. What files are in the transport / temp folders? As nick says, disk space? And windows event errors/warnings. Remember publishing and transport are done on an OS and through a network - the cms tool isn’t the only variable here. :)

Comment: The above comments assume you’ve confirmed the endpoints are reachable, topman and oauth etc are (still) in order (again - it’s not just the cms _folks_ - you have to consider firewall, windows and sql stakeholders and their activities/actions too.

Comment: I've seen the unexpected error. IRC it was indeed a disk space issue on the Delivery server.

Comment: Check this as well,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553444/status-in-publishing-queue-stays-on-ready-for-transport-even-for-items-that-pu

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for failure in the transport phase is connectivity with the deployer having issues.

The Publisher service is responsible for creating the transport package. In your case, the package was created and hitting at an issue with the Transport service.

Worth review to try increasing the SendTimeout and Polling Timeout values in cd_transport_conf.xml. The  SendTimeout default is the 60s.

```
<Polling MaxAttempts="900" Timeout="15" Interval="5000"/>

<Senders SendTimeout="960000"/>
```

Restart the transport service for this change to take effect.

Also, try to clean up the tomcat temp files from C:\Windows\Temp and also clean up the WorkFolder transactions the location where temporary files are stored if there are any files in the CM Publisher box.

If still issue exists then you can enable the TRACE logs of the transport service (cd_core and cd_transport logs) for further troubleshooting to see what is going on.